# Vite 4.4.9 doesn't react on shortcuts

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite

Did anyone of you had a problem that vite in Dev server after a while it doesn't react on shortcuts.
It still works, serves the app normally but doesn't react on anything Ctrl+C, h, q, nothing.

Config and plugin:

```
import { defineConfig, loadEnv, splitVendorChunkPlugin } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import svgr from 'vite-plugin-svgr';
import tsconfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths';
import checker from 'vite-plugin-checker';
import path from 'path';

export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => {
  let env = loadEnv(mode, process.cwd(), "VITE_APP");

  env.NODE_ENV = mode;

  const envWithProcessPrefix = {
    "process.env": `${JSON.stringify(env)}`,
  };

  return {
    build: {
      outDir: 'build',
      sourcemap: true,
    },
    server: {
      port: process.env.PORT ?? 3000,
      watch: {
        ignored: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, './coverage'),
          path.resolve(__dirname, './build'),
          path.resolve(__dirname, './storybook-static'),
          /\.test\.(ts|tsx)$/
        ]
      }
    },
    define: envWithProcessPrefix,
    plugins: [
      splitVendorChunkPlugin(),
      react({
        exclude: /\.test\.(ts|tsx)$/
      }),
      tsconfigPaths(),
      svgr(
        {
          svgrOptions: {}
        }
      ),
      checker({
        typescript: true,
      }),
    ],
  };
});
```

Tried everything, like just react() as plugin and strip config to the basics, still the same.

Like it just looses SIG* whatever for whatever reason. Can't debug that.